# AppConfig key value pair

Tags: .net

In my application there is a requirement to remove special characters from a string. I am able to achieve this by reading a string of special chars from config appsettinf key-value pair.

EX :

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ExcludeSpecialChars" value ="%'^"/>
</appSettings>
```

I am facing problem when I include & in the value
ex :

```
key="ExcludeSpecialChars" value ="&%'^"
```

The application fails to build and shows an error "cannot parse the entity".

Is there any workaround so that I can include `&` in the special chars string?

Answer (score 6):

Since .NET .config files are XML, use the [entity](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) `&amp;` to represent an ampersand:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ExcludeSpecialChars" value ="&amp;%'^"/>
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 5):

> Some characters have a special meaning in XML.
>
> If you place a character like "&" inside an XML element, it will
>   generate an error because the parser interprets it as the start of a
>   new element.

you can use `&amp;`  there are 5 predefined entity references in XML

```
&lt;    <   less than
&gt;    >   greater than
&amp;   &   ampersand 
&apos;  '   apostrophe
&quot;  "   quotation mark
```

ref :http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp